# Only xpath for extracting text for multiple conditions in xml - no code possible

Tags: xpath

I have an example file with three conditions to be met... I also have no control over the xml file I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootelement>
<Description>
    <Note countries="AR,GB,US" >
        <P countries="AR" >We want this one as it's AR.</P>
        <P countries="US" >We don't want this one as it's not AR.</P>
        <P countries="GB" >We don't want this either as it's not AR.</P>
    </Note>
</Description>
<Description>
    <Note countries="AR,GB,US" >
        <P>Everyone in AR, GB and US gets to buy.</P>
        <P>No restrictions for this product in these countries.</P>
    </Note>
</Description>
<Description>
    <Note>
        <P>No country, that's because it will be treated as AR.</P>
    </Note>
</Description>
</rootelement>
```

The task is threefold:

1. Extract text from <P> where countries="AR", other values are always ignored
2. Extract text from <P> where it's parent element (in this example  but it's not always the case) contains AR in the countries attribute (countries="AR,GB,US" for example)
3. Extract text from current element (<P> in this example, not always) when there is no countries attribute present in the current element or it's ancestors

I hope that's clear, I tried to put three examples in the xml above and I need to extract these texts with my rule(s):

```
<P countries="AR" >We want this one as it's AR.</P>
<P>Everyone in AR, GB and US gets to buy.</P>
<P>No restrictions for this product in these countries.</P>
<P>No country, that's because it will be treated as AR.</P>
```

Ideally I want one rule.  But I could use several as the rules are applied hierarchically.

If I use this in the application I'm feeding:

```
//*[contains(@countries,'AR')]/*
```

All good to get the first three, but I also get US and GB which I don't want.  I can exclude them with this:

```
//*[contains(@countries,'AR')]/*[not(contains(@countries,'US')) and not(contains(@countries,'GB'))]
```

But the expression will become unmanageable in practice as there are many languages and I often need to change the ones I'm looking for.  I cannot figure out how to say just exclude any that don't contain AR.

And then I still have the last problem of being able to extract if the countries attribute is missing altogether.  This bit I'm at a complete loss to know how to resolve without affecting the previous results.

Comment: what version of XPath?

Comment: @ConalTuohy - XPath 1, so your expression was good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an XPath 1 expression which I think captures the logic you've described:

```xml
//*[text()[normalize-space()]]
   [
      not(ancestor-or-self::*/@countries) or 
      contains(ancestor-or-self::*[@countries][1]/@countries, 'AR')
   ]
```

Any element which has a child text node which is not just white space, and

- which has no `countries` attribute of its own or on any of its ancestor elements, or
- has 'AR' either in its own `countries` attribute or the first `countries` attribute of any of its ancestors.

NB the [`ancestor-or-self` axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes) is a 'reverse' axis which means the expression `ancestor-or-self::*` will return the context node itself, then its parent, then its grand-parent, etc, in that order, finishing at the root element of the document. The expression `ancestor-or-self::*[@countries]` will filter that list to include only the elements which have a `countries` attribute, and `ancestor-or-self::*[@countries][1]` will return the first element in that list. If the element that contains the text has a countries attribute, then it will be first in that list, otherwise the nearest ancestor will be first. I think this "inheritance" is what you're wanting to achieve?

Results:

```xml
<P countries="AR">We want this one as it's AR.</P>
<P>Everyone in AR, GB and US gets to buy.</P>
<P>No restrictions for this product in these countries.</P>
<P>No country, that's because it will be treated as AR.</P>
```

Comment: Thanks Conal, that is genius!  I learned a lot from this, much appreciated.  Unfortunately I'm too new to be able to score the answer apparently.